# Scala - aggregating tuples

Tags: scala, tuples, aggregate

I have a list of tuples:

```
val serverList = List(
    ("AS-4019", 100),
    ("BR-5722", 2080),
    ("SQ-9985", 70),
    ("BR-5722", 82),
    ("BR-5722", 147),
    ("AS-4019", 7),
    ("SQ-9985", 29),
    ("AS-4019", 64),
    ("SQ-9985", 93),
    ("GN-1070", 1408),
    ("BR-5722", 19),
    ("GN-1070", 7798))
```

The string is a server identifier, the number is related to the server load and each tuple represents a project accessing a server.

I need to aggregate this list into a:

```
List(serverNameString, accessCountInt, serverLoadInt)
```

Result should look something like this:

```
List(
    ("AS-4019", 3, 171),
    ("BR-5722", 4, 2328),
    ("SQ-9985", 3, 192),
    ("GN-1070", 2, 9206))
```

I've tried using some maps and filters but it seems overly complex and also doesn't work.

```
val aggregatedList = for(v <- lisinputt.distinct) {
    (v, lisinputt.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)(v))
}
```

Comment: `serverList.groupBy(_._1).map {case (key, values) => (key, values.length, values.map(_._2).sum) }`

Comment: @XavierGuihot A very clean and concise solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the input list

```
val serverList = List(
  ("AS-4019", 100),
  ("BR-5722", 2080),
  ("SQ-9985", 70),
  ("BR-5722", 82),
  ("BR-5722", 147),
  ("AS-4019", 7),
  ("SQ-9985", 29),
  ("AS-4019", 64),
  ("SQ-9985", 93),
  ("GN-1070", 1408),
  ("BR-5722", 19),
  ("GN-1070", 7798))
```

This can be achieved by

```
serverList.groupBy(_._1).map {
  x => ( x._1, x._2.size , x._2.map(_._2).sum )
}
```

which will give you result in the form of

```
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(String, Int, Int)] = List((AS-4019,3,171), (SQ-9985,3,192), (BR-5722,4,2328), (GN-1070,2,9206))
```